# unexpected result from find()

Tags: mongodb

guys i have a collection with documents that look like this

```
> db.patient.find().pretty()

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e1f5165da4c015b2bdacedc"),
        "firstname" : "max",
        "lastname" : "schwarzmullar",
        "age" : "29",
        "history" : [
                {
                        "disease" : "cold",
                        "treatment" : "cataflam"
                },
                {
                        "disease" : "inflamation",
                        "treatment" : "augmenten"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e1f5353da4c015b2bdacedd"),
        "firstname" : "3abas",
        "lastname" : "hamada",
        "age" : "25",
        "history" : [
                {
                        "disease" : "ich",
                        "treatment" : "cataflam"
                },
                {
                        "disease" : "inflamation",
                        "treatment" : "augmenten"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e1f535eda4c015b2bdacede"),
        "firstname" : "falkasa",
        "lastname" : "elsokary",
        "age" : 39,
        "history" : {
                "disease" : "exhaustion",
                "treatment" : "panadol"
        }
}
```

but when i try to search for any document with age gt than 25 it is only giving me one document despite as above you see two document with the mentioned criteria , please clarify that or correct me

```
> db.patient.find({age :{$gt:25}}).pretty()

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e1f535eda4c015b2bdacede"),
        "firstname" : "falkasa",
        "lastname" : "elsokary",
        "age" : 39,
        "history" : {
                "disease" : "exhaustion",
                "treatment" : "panadol"
        }
}
> db.patient.find({age :{$gt:25}}).pretty()
```

Comment: Ok for some documents your age seems to be a string & your query has a number `{age :{$gt:25}}`, types should match, As you're getting `39` back is because `number` matches with `number` - So condition does apply on those documents !!

Comment: Do you still need help to get it done as with same data or are you updating your collection to have all ages as `int` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your collection you have `"age" : "29" , "age" : "25"`  so 25 and 29 are strings now ,  just edit the ages in  your collection

> age : 29 , age : 25

Comment: thanks a lot , i have updated them to numbers and it worked

Comment: @MohamadMostafa if you find the answer helpful, please mark it as the accepted answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers